# How to Clear Previous data from Slick Slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am using the following code to show the data which is called when I click on one button. When I click on second button the new data comes and that will be shown.

```
/*-------SLIDER ANIMATION (START)----------*/
$scope.getBikeAds = function (reqobj) {
  var request = {
    authToken : '',
    cityName : reqobj.name ? reqobj.name : 'Bangaluru'
  };
  mainService.getBikesModels(request).then(function (success) {
    $scope.bikesAds = [];
    if (success && success.data.errorMessage == 'Success') {
      $scope.bikesAds = enlargeBikeImage(success.data.data.bikeModels);    //For 2x Image        
      $timeout(function() {
        if($('.regular2').hasClass("slick-initialized"))
          $('.regular2').slick('unslick'); 
          $(".regular2").slick({
            infinite: true,
            lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            variableWidth: true,
            responsive: [
              {
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {
                  arrows: true,
                  centerMode: true,
                  centerPadding: '40px',
                  slidesToShow: 1
                }
              },
              {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                  arrows: true,
                  centerMode: true,
                  centerPadding: '26px',
                  slidesToShow: 1
                }
              }
            ]
          });
      },0);
    } else {
      $scope.bikesAds = [];
    }
  });
};
 /*-------SLIDER ANIMATION (END)----------*/
$scope.closeBikeAdsSlider = function() {
    $scope.bikesAds = [];
    $scope.checked = false;
    $( "#effect" ).toggle( 'scale', 500 );
    $scope.cityName = "";
};
```

When I click on the next button the data which is already came from the previous service call is adding up with the new data. How to clear the previous data when the slick is close or open?